# jQuery find div with data attr

Tags: jquery

So, I have following markup:

```
<div class="yay" data-pi="23"></div>
<div class="yay" data-pi="24"></div>
<div class="yay" data-pi="25"></div>
<div class="yay" data-pi="26"></div>
```

I am looking for a specific div with `data-pi"26"`.

This is what I have:

```
var my_class = jQuery('.yay').find("[data-pi="26"]");
```

In other words, I want to find the div that contains `data-pi=26`. Do I have it right?

thanks

Comment: The `.find()` method will select descendant elements. You want `$('.yay[data-pi="26"]')` in order to select `.yay` elements with that data attribute.

Comment: I see. that's what I had it wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the quotation marks right. This is what I would have used:

```
var my_class = $("div.yay[data-pi='26']");
```

`.find()` actually finds the elements **inside** `.yay` element, so try my code.

Comment: Thanks for the help! =)

Comment: @steveKim no probs. Please accept the answer once you make sure it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, you don't need jQuery for this:

```
var my_div = document.querySelector("div[data-pi='26']")
```

http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

MDN reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started/Selectors

Comment: I see. I will implement this. Thanks for the useful info. =)